# POST data to url in php

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, post

I am fetching data through url, but it does not show any record on `user_id`.  The value `ali40` is present in the database, but records are not being shown

http://celeritas-solutions.com/emrapp/surveyDescription.php?user_id=ali40

```
<?php 


   $linkID = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host.");
```

mysql_select_db($database, $linkID) or die("Could not find database.");

```
  if (!function_exists('json_encode'))


  {


  function json_encode($a=false)

 {

 if (is_null($a)) return 'null';
 if ($a === false) return 'false';
 if ($a === true) return 'true';
 if (is_scalar($a))
  {
   if (is_float($a))
   {
    // Always use "." for floats.
    return floatval(str_replace(",", ".", strval($a)));
    }



    if (is_string($a))
    {
      static $jsonReplaces = array(array("\\", "/", "\n", "\t", "\r", "\b", "\f", '"'), array('\\\\', '\\/', '\\n', '\\t', '\\r', '\\b', '\\f', '\"'));
     return '"' . str_replace($jsonReplaces[0], $jsonReplaces[1], $a) . '"';
    }
    else
    return $a;
}
$isList = true;
for ($i = 0, reset($a); $i < count($a); $i++, next($a))
{
  if (key($a) !== $i)
  {
    $isList = false;
    break;
  }
}
$result = array();
if ($isList)
{
  foreach ($a as $v) $result[] = json_encode($v);
  return '[' . join(',', $result) . ']';
 }
 else
 {
  foreach ($a as $k => $v) $result[] = json_encode($k).':'.json_encode($v);
  return '{' . join(',', $result) . '}';
 }
 }
}



  $user_id=$_GET['user_id'];






  echo($user_id);




   $query = mysql_query("SELECT s.*, u.user_id FROM survey_master AS s JOIN user_profile AS u on u.user_id = s.user_id where s.user_id='".$user_id."' ");




  $rows = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $rows[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($rows);

 ?>
```

Comment: Please post a description of your problem here along with the relevant code. That way visitors who are trying to help you don't have to go to your website. It also means that future readers will be able to see what your problem was and learn from it, even after you've fixed it on your site.

Comment: use [*file_get_contents*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: you tagged the question as PHP - but now that you posted the code - it doesn't look like php...

Comment: @Mr.Alien i have added php code also

Comment: @alfasin i have added php code also

Comment: @alfasin can you epxlain me more please

Answer (score 0):

Procedural PHP.

Before using mysql_fetch_assoc execute the sql using :

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

then use:

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
```

Comment: user1520252 : Use mysql_query() insert your SQL in that before calling mysql_fetch_assoc, else result will be NULL.

Comment: Fabricio, I did not just change the variable names, if you read it nicely, I have added a function which user1520252 has missed.

Comment: $query = mysql_query("SELECT s.*, u.user_id FROM survey_master AS s JOIN user_profile AS u on u.user_id = s.user_id where s.user_id='".$user_id."' ");

Comment: Here we have the query being executed: `$query = mysql_query("SELECT s.*, u.user_id FROM survey_master AS s JOIN user_profile AS u on u.user_id = s.user_id where s.user_id='".$user_id."' ");` Then the result being fetched: `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {` I've read the question and answer 3 times, yet I didn't see much difference.

Comment: @FabricoMatte yes there is no problem in querry i think becuase when i call this script from html page and giving input by using textbox then it shows result but when i give in url the value it does not show

Comment: @FabricioMatte have you seen my comment

Comment: @user1520252 Yes sorry, I'm a little busy over here. If I had a solution I'd submit it.